# Get response size (and other variables) in an external file with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I managed to generate an external file that shows me the entire response. I need now to get the size of the response I'm getting in the same external file, in order to have an easier debugging phase. Also, it would be more practical to overwrite this file every time I'm doing a test.

I tried to modified my Beanshell PostProcessor to do so, but I wasn't able to do the job with my knowledge, But here is the code I'm getting right now to generate the external file with the whole response, it's actually pretty simple :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

File file = new File("D:\\jMeterResponseForLH.txt");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);
```

Right now, I have no idea on how to get the data I'm interested in. Do you have any idea on how I can get it? Also, do you know if there is a function to overwrite the file at every test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (instead of Beanshell) and use [prev](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseDataAsString--) to get data

```
new File("D:\\jMeterResponseForLH.txt").text = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
```

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult (if any)

- Use default language groovy

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will use the prev and several functions to get parameters directly into the log output file. Very useful way to do it, thank you very much!

Just one more thing, do you know if there is way to get only a part of the response in my external file? I have response up to 70 millions of char, I would like to get only a part of it. Do you have any idea to do so, please? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Armelias You can do substring with size, e.g. `prev.getResponseDataAsString().substring(0,1000)`

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your advices, it really helped!